# Why is my audio glitching out?

Tags: audio

With Windows 10, about every 15 seconds when audio is playing or it seems to get high enough, I'll hear a "rrrrrr". I've tried lowering the Realtek HD Audio quality, tried a headset and speakers, lowered the volume, but it still persists.

Comment: I also have a problem with audio on win10. The sound enchantment sounds really bad. I can disable it in speaker properties, but it will only until affect (for example) the current youtube video, but it gets glitchy at the next video and I have to disable it again (although the check-mark for "disable all audio effects" is still there)

Comment: It seems to have gone away for me, at least for now. Check your programs for "crapware" that got on your computer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't have anything to do with the programs I'm running.